# Comments section and comment blocks in C

Tags: c, comments

Accordingly to [Doxygen's manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html), there are some standards to correctly comment a program written in C. Unfortunately the way of documenting a program doesn't seem to be well standardized (i.e. GNU Coding Standards).

If I agree that the most common header for a function is:

```
/** 
 * Brief description.
 *
 * @param a first parameter
 * @return if any return value
 * 
 * Detailed description
 **/
```

Unfortunately this solution is quite tiresome when I need to quickly comment a block of code with `/*` ... `*/`. It is the reason why I prefer using `//` which doesn't interact with `/*..*/`. So what is the most advisable way of writing function comment header? Also most of the today's standards are based on a legacy C89 standards.

Second point of my question concerns the section comments. I often have in different sections in my code that I would like to clearly separate. For example:

```
/**
 * @file foo.c
 *
 * StackOverflow Example
 **/

/*************************************************************
 * Includes
 ************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
...

/*************************************************************
 * Prototypes
 ************************************************************/
void foo();
void bar();
...
```

Is there any C programming standard largely used that precisely define how to write such separators based on a study (less cumbersome, less tiring for the eyes, most used by the community, ...)?

Comment: As far as i know how to seperate sections is not define you can do what erver you want!

Comment: @Rizier123 This is also what I think but in the case of programming I hate when I can do what ever I want to do. If there is any standards I prefer to stick to it.

Comment: then set your own standards ! (Make your own coding guidelines)

Comment: @Rizier123 That's what everybody does :(

Comment: I mean how should we help you now? You have to decide how your programming stile looks!

Comment: If you're using doxygen, why not go all the way and keep everything compatible with it? For instance, it has `\section` and `\subsection` which can also function as separators. If you find its syntax tiresome, you could set your editor to spit out snippets with a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it comes down to preference and readability.

For example I like to use the following:

```
/*----------------------
 | Function
 | Author: 
 | Dependencies:
 ----------------------*/


/*----------------------
 |  Section
 -----------------------*/

//Comments in sections
```

I use this in conjunction with the following rules for readability.

- 2 line returns before a section heading/Comment
- 1 line return after a section heading/Comment

The easiest way I have found to block quote is to highlight the code and then to use the keyboard short-cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to comment out that block.  Works in most editors.

Hope that helps.